# xml serializer causes nullreference in photon rpc comand

Tags: c#, xml, nullreferenceexception, serialization

I get this code xml serializer and tried to get it worked but the created object contains nullreference

```
public  byte[] SerializeObject <T>(T serializableObject)
{
    T obj = serializableObject;

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        x.Serialize (stream,obj);

        return stream.ToArray ();
    }
}

public  T DeserializeObject <T>(byte[] serilizedBytes)
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer (typeof(T));

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(serilizedBytes)) 
    {
        return (T) x.Deserialize (stream);
    } 
}
```

I initialize class variables using this function and I can't find where is the null

```
public void updateinfo(int []card, int lmin, int lbom, int pass, int mxint,int cardinturn, int lastsim, int fplayer, float ang, int playid,string namepl,int numberofcard){
    o1=new playerupdates();
    o1.cardstoad = new int[card.Length];
    for(int i=0;i<card.Length;i++){
        o1.cardstoad[i]=card[i];
    }
o1.lastmin=lmin;
o1.lastbomb=lbom;
o1.passnumber=pass;
o1.maxvalueinturn=mxint;
o1.cardsinturn=cardinturn;
o1.lastsimiliarvalue=lastsim;
o1.firstplayer=fplayer;
o1.angle=ang;
o1.playerid=playid; 
o1.playername=namepl;
o1.cardsin=numberofcard;

}
```

I have searchrd for a solution but nothing. Is correct the function that initialises the class variables?
edit
class code

```
public int []cardstoad { get; set; }
public int lastmin { get; set; }
public int lastbomb { get; set; }
public int passnumber{ get; set; } 
public int maxvalueinturn { get; set; }
public int cardsinturn { get; set; }
public int lastsimiliarvalue { get; set; }
public int firstplayer { get; set; }
public float angle{ get; set; }
public int playerid { get; set; }
public string playername { get; set; }
public int cardsin{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Post a sample XML please. Also the class you use for serialization (playerupdates I guess)

Comment: I added class code. I remove cardstoad  and for other variables in updateinfo i did that o1=new playerupdates(){lastmin=lmin,
lastbomb=lbom,etc}; but nothing. Nullreference stills again

Comment: There's nothing in this code that uses XML serialization and no XML sample.

Comment: updateinfo(lastmin,lastbomb,passnumber,maxvalueinturn,cardsinturn,lastsimiliarvalue,firstplayer,angle,playerid,playername,playercardsc);
photonView.RPC("updatecardsintable",PhotonTargets.All,selem.SerializeObject(o1),Serelemen.cards);                                                                 selem.SerializeObject(o1) contains nullreference I have given SerializeObject function. see the code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is o1 isn't doing anything.  updateinfo is settting the values but o1 is being lost after returning from updateinfo.  See code below for corrections

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] card = {1,2,3,4,5};
            int lmin = 4;
            int lbom = 5;
            int pass = 6;
            int mxint = 7;
            int cardinturn = 8;
            int lastsim = 9;
            int fplayer = 10;
            float ang = 30.0F;
            int playid = 100;
            string namepl = "abc";
            int numberofcard = 26;
            playerupdates pU = new playerupdates();
            pU.updateinfo(card, lmin, lbom, pass, mxint, cardinturn, lastsim, fplayer, ang, playid, namepl, numberofcard);
            byte[] data = pU.SerializeObject<playerupdates>(pU);
            string test = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);    //test to see if serialize is working correctly
            playerupdates newPU = pU.DeserializeObject<playerupdates>(data);
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot("playerupdates")]
    public class playerupdates
    {
        [XmlElement("cardstoad")]
        public int[] cardstoad { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("lastmin")]
        public int lastmin { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("lastbomb")]
        public int lastbomb { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("passnumber")]
        public int passnumber { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("maxvalueinturn")]
        public int maxvalueinturn { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("cardsinturn")]
        public int cardsinturn { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("lastsimiliarvalue")]
        public int lastsimiliarvalue { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("firstplayer")]
        public int firstplayer { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("angle")]
        public float angle { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("playerid")]
        public int playerid { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("playername")]
        public string playername { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("cardsin")]
        public int cardsin { get; set; }

        public void  updateinfo(int[] card, int lmin, int lbom, int pass, int mxint, int cardinturn, int lastsim, int fplayer, float ang, int playid, string namepl, int numberofcard)
        {
            //o1 not needed
            //playerupdates o1 = new playerupdates();
            cardstoad = new int[card.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < card.Length; i++)
            {
                cardstoad[i] = card[i];
            }
            lastmin = lmin;
            lastbomb = lbom;
            passnumber = pass;
            maxvalueinturn = mxint;
            cardsinturn = cardinturn;
            lastsimiliarvalue = lastsim;
            firstplayer = fplayer;
            angle = ang;
            playerid = playid;
            playername = namepl;
            cardsin = numberofcard;
        }

        public byte[] SerializeObject<T>(T serializableObject)
        {
            T obj = serializableObject;

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

                x.Serialize(stream, obj);

                return stream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public T DeserializeObject<T>(byte[] serilizedBytes)
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(serilizedBytes))
            {
                return (T)x.Deserialize(stream);
            }
        }

    }
}
​
```

Comment: updateinfo is not in the playerupdates but in another class where is main function this is the reason why playerupdates o1 = new playerupdates(){} but anyway I want to ask if those functions are serialised when the function serialise is called .If no please let me know

Comment: The code I posted was fully tested.  the answer to your question is "no".  The variable o1 is a local variable and the value is disposed after  updateinfo is executed.  If you made o1 a public variable in another class then it would be serialized.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it solves nullreference in serialise but in deserialise it shows nullreference public void updatecardsintable(byte [] crdstotable){
  playerupdates o2 = selem.DeserializeObject<playerupdates>(crdstotable);
lastmin=o2.lastmin;
  lastbomb=o2.lastbomb;
  passnumber=o2.passnumber;
  maxvalueinturn=o2.maxvalueinturn;
  cardsinturn=o2.cardsinturn;
  lastsimiliarvalue=o2.lastsimiliarvalue;
  firstplayer=o2.firstplayer;
  angle=o2.angle;
  playerid=o2.playerid; 
  playername=o2.playername;
  cardsin=o2.cardsin;
 }

Comment: Your answer is the right solution but The problem is photonnetwork. or this line playerupdates o2 = selem.DeserializeObject<playerupdates>(crdstotable); what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Need to see xml.  Make sure the tags in XML matches the [Xml...] statements including upper/lower case.  Also check array items like cardstoad.  I used XmlElement which only creates single level of tags instead of two layers <cardstoad><cardstoad></cardstoad></cardstoad>.  Also make sure objects are "public".

Comment: after a cleanup everything went well